# Cutting a rod dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm

Given a rod of length n inches and an array of prices that contains prices of all pieces of the size smaller than n. Using dynamic programming we can get the maximum value and corresponding pieces of the rod. Is there any algorithm which will produce kth maximum value with the corresponding cut for this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rod Cutting - Dynamic Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522640/rod-cutting-dynamic-programming)

Comment: @ilim rod cutting problem gives maximum value with the corresponding split of the rod. My question is how to get the second, third, fourth... maximum with the corresponding split of rod.

Comment: To my understanding, it would be possible to modify the algorithm to use more than one array for the solution values, namely one for the optimal value, one for the second best value and so on. These arrays would have to be filled along the optimal array.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem : Find `k th` max price for rod cutting problem.**

I think the algorithm can be tweaked in following way :

Change the recursion in rod cutting problem from  :

```
cutRod(n) = max(price[i] + cutRod(n-i-1)) for all i in {0, 1 .. n-1}
```

To :

```
Top_K_Price_CutRod(n)[] = top_k(price[i] + cutRod(n-i-1)) for all i in {0, 1 .. n-1}
```

Basically, at every recursion step, return max `k` prices for that subpart, because only those can be eventually in overall maximum `k` .

Bruteforce way is to return all the possible prices of that subpart, but we know for sure that prices which have rank greater than `k` for this subpart, can't be in top `k` prices of complete rod eventually.

So here `Top_K_Price_CutRod(n)[]` is an array of `k` max prices for that subpart.
At root of the recursion, you will be left with max top `k` prices.

I don't think we can optimize more than this, as at every recursion node its top k value can be among final top k. So u have to top `k` values for all subparts.